# Regex replace period with dash for URL formatting

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a query that returns first and last names which are output in a URL like so:

```
<a href="#fname#-#lname#>#fname# #lname#</a>
```

outputs:

```
<a href="john-doe">John Doe</a>
```

Problem is for names having a period at start or end of name, I need to reformat the name in the url to be as follows:

```
Doe, John G. --> <a href="doe-g-john">Doe, John G.</a>

Doe, G. John --> <a href="g-john-doe">Doe, G. John</a>

Flannery Jr., William J. --> <a href="william-j-flannery-jr">Flannery Jr., William J.</a>
```

Can I use rereplace function or some kind of regex to account for reformatting these 3 scenarios?

```
#REReplace(getAuthors.Fname, "\.^", "",ALL)#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you!

Jon

Comment: Why not use the urlencoded() function instead?

Comment: (Edit) The examples above appear to do more than a simple replace. The contents are rearranged as well. What determines the result and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using replaceList function - Thanks for posting solutions anyway!

```
<a href="replaceList(getAuthors.Fname, " ,.,", "-")#-replaceList(getAuthors.Lname, " ,.,", "-")#">#getAuthors.Lname#, #getAuthors.Fname#</a>
```